# Mercurial clone works locally, doesn't work over ssh

Tags: mercurial, ssh

Can't figure this out.

This works locally on machinex.com:

```
hg clone /somepath/repos mystuff
```

But I try this remotely:

```
hg clone ssh://myuser@machinex.com/somepath/repos mystuff
```

I get this:

```
myuser's password: [enter password correctly]
remote: abort: There is no Mercurial repository here (.hg not found)!
abort: no suitable response from remote hg!
```

I can ssh into machinex.com just fine, too.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the path via ssh is relative to the root directory (i.e., /), you need an extra slash:

```
hg clone ssh://myuser@machinex.com//somepath/repos mystuff
```

else it thinks it is relative to myuser's home directory.

Comment: If your path happens to be `ssh://myuser@machinex.com//cygdrive/d/repos` then give `ssh://myuser@machinex.com/D:/repos` a try. (it worked for me)